# xcode5 jump to definition not working properly

Tags: xcode5

In Xcode 4.6, when u cmd+click a function name and meantime existing mutiple implemetation, it will show selection list.

In Xcode5 nothing shows but directly jumping to random implementation.

Has anyone notice this bug and know how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

No, I have not seen this in XCode 5. I have Version 5.0 (5A1413) and it works as you described for XCode 4.6

Similarly in XCode 5, if I ctrl-click a method and select "Jump to definition" from the contextual menu it shows the selection list if there are multiple possible destinations.